# Dvorak layout with Qwerty hotkeys (Dvorak — Qwerty Ctrl)

Tags: 11.04, 10.10, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, dvorak

How can I use Qwerty hotkeys with the Dvorak keyboard layout? For example I want `C` to map to `J`, but `Ctrl + C` to remain as `Ctrl + C`.

The [dvorak-qwerty program](http://code.google.com/p/dvorak-qwerty/) is supposed to do this, but does not work for me.

Desired behaviour seems to occur in the terminal and with foreign language layouts.

Comment: Any particular version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @Rinzwind: I'm using 10.10, but this layout would be worth the hassle of updating if need be.

Comment: you can bind alt+c and alt+v or whatever you are looking for to XF86Copy and XF86Paste which doesn't work everywhere but gets you partially the way there.

Comment: So Synergy should work theoretically but I haven't had time to test it lately.  It basically allows you to remotely control another computer from Mac or Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Please see this bug and the long and heated discussion around it: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=162726

The behaviour you want was actually the default behaviour before and was considered a bug by people using the Dvorak layout...

PS: That it works in gnome-terminal is considered a bug...

Answer (score 1):

Reported on Launchpad as [bug 794510](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/794510). Reported on GNOME Bugzilla as [bug 652104](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=652104).

> #### No option to use Qwerty hotkeys in alternative Latin keyboard layouts
>
> Some users prefer to use an alternative Latin layout such as Dvorak to increase their typing speed. Many of these users prefer to use the original Qwerty keyboard shortcuts which are conveniently positioned (e.g. Ctrl: C-Copy, V-Paste, S-Save). An option should be provided to use Qwerty hotkeys with alternative layouts.
>
> Qwerty hotkeys are already used in the terminal and in non-latin keyboard layouts. Qwerty hotkeys were used in all keyboard layouts before [bug 162726](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=162726) was fixed.

GNOME Bugzilla [bug 162726](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=162726) argues the converse; [comment directing to new bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=162726#c133) added.