# Can't get shortcut to work in gnome

Tags: gnome, xdotool

I'm trying to set up qwerty shortcuts with dvorak layout but can't seem to send the key presses can someone look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFlpr.jpg) and tell me what I am doing wrong xdotool is working if I manually run it in terminal so I don't think that is my problem.
I have been able to get a single word command with no problem so perhaps it is something to do with xdotool or the quotation marks. If I remove them then the command doesn't run and it just prints the letter.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to see if the shortcut was disabled in ubuntu? I simulated your scenario,  and found when I clicked on 'Disabled', then typed the shortcut I wanted under 'new acceleration', the keys responded.

In other words, when you hit "Apply", did you enable the key presses through Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean however I was able to get it to work with another command that is one word so perhaps it has something to do with the quotation marks without them it ignores the shortcut completely and just types the letter I press.

Comment: I don't think, from my research, this has anything to do with placing the commands in quotes. Depending on which version of xdtool you are using, it may be a bug. Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/35803/dvorak-layout-with-qwerty-hotkeys-dvorak-qwerty-ctrl.  I'm sorry; I am just a beginner with Ubuntu's keyboard. :)